# Phalcon PHP : Jquery Datatable Server Side individual column filtering only gives first pages selection options

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, server-side, phalcon

Here is my Jquery Server Side DataTable set up, correctly returning data from my database and the filtering does actually work, but the problem is that the selection box for each column only shows values off the first page of data.

And i m using mysql database for this

**Phalcon PHP Controller Action :**

```
public function getJsonBOMuploadAction($dummy) {
    if ($this->request->isAjax()) {
        $this->setJsonResponse();
            $request = $this->request;
            $p_draw = $request->getPost("draw");
            $p_start = $request->getPost("start");
            $p_length = $request->getPost("length");
            $p_search = $this->GetSearchString($request->getPost("search"));
            $p_col_search = $this->GetSearchString($request->getPost("columns"));

            try {
                $data = CallableRoutine::getDocumentRouterList($p_start
                                , $p_length, $p_search, intval($p_col_search[0])
                                , $p_col_search[1], $p_col_search[2]);
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                return $ex;
            }

            $count = $data[count($data) - 1]["id"];
            array_splice($data, count($data) - 1);
            return Array("data" => $data,
                "draw" => $p_draw,
                "recordsFiltered" => $count,
                "search" => $p_search,
                "col_search" => $p_col_search,
                "recordsTotal" => $count);
        }
    }
```

**Jquery Code :**

```
        vm.initExampleDocrouterDatatable = function() {
            $('#example_docrouter').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "./product_bom/getJsonBOMupload",
                    "type": "POST"
                },
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "id"},
                    {"data": "name"},
                    {"data": "description"}
                ],
                // ==============================================================
                // ====== Column filter code reference:
                // ====== https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select
                initComplete: function () {
                    this.api().columns().every( function () {
                        var column = this;
                        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                            .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                            .on( 'change', function () {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                    $(this).val()
                                );

                                column
                                    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                    .draw();
                            } );

                        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                        } );
                    } );
                }
            });
        };
```

**Here Is My HTML :**

```
 <table id="example_docrouter" class="table row-border hover table-responsive display nowrap table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="thbg thead-css">ID</th>
                    <th class="thbg thead-css">Name</th>
                    <th class="thbg thead-css">Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot class="noprint">
                <tr>
                    <th class="thead-css">ID</th>
                    <th class="thead-css">Name</th>
                    <th class="thead-css">Description</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody></tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently with  $p_length you are doing some pagination. Is not clear where does this value come from, you might find useful to work with Phalcon paginator:  https://docs.phalconphp.com/zh/3.2/db-pagination

Comment: Actually that value come from mysql stored procedure and i call stored prodedure in my callable routine after that i call my callable routine in php action

Comment: If it's correct to assume that $p_length works like MySQL LIMIT, are you getting back the total count of records? Otherwise you'll have to fiddle with OFFSET and LIMIT to get all the results in incremental steps. Make a var_dump from the resultset and check if it is Phalcon not returning all the data or if it is the resultset from the stored procedure the one that is not delivering it all.

Comment: Okay I'll Check That

Comment: How did it go? If your datasets are very big, you might find this interesting as well: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#mysqlnd